# How can i open .trace file format(traceview) without DDMS?

Tags: android, profiling, trace, ddms

I want to save  a log of method calls.
Traceview supports that function and I can get .trace file format.

but, I need to open .trace file format without DDMS.

If I can't open .trace file without DDMS, How can I get a log of method calls?
(The best is .txt file format.)

thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? Or if either below suffices you might want to indicate that. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

It is an old thread.
because I found here, so other guys may need this, too.
Try this:

```
traceview -r yourtrace.trace > 1.txt
```

and look 1.txt has any useful thing to u.

Comment: one of the best solution :)

Answer (score 7):

"traceview" is a command-line utility.  You don't need to launch it from DDMS.

If you just want a text file with times and message names, you can use "dmtracedump -o file.trace".

Answer (score 1):

Well for one, you should just use DDMS it's very simple to work with. Even if you don't have eclipse you can use the one that shipped with the SDK. However, if you already have access to the `tracefile.trace` then you could simply use [`Traceview`](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) from the SDK. Simply open your command prompt and navigate to your android `SDK/tools` directory as such: `cd C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools`. Once there simply type `traceview` followed by the filename (can omit .trace) as such: `traceview C:\Users\Sino\Desktop\Janky_trace_file`. This should open your trace file in a GUI representation with functionality to delve into your method calls.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple.
**Eclipse: File --> Open file --> open traveview file (xxxx.trace)**

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ".trace" file, just use "traceview " from the command line and you should be able to view the content of the file.
You can generate various graphs with the existing .trace file using the command line tool "dmtracedump". http://developer.android.com/tools/help/dmtracedump.html.