# ListFragment was not created in setcontentview of main_activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, oncreate, setcontentview

Hope it's my last issue with Fragments :)

I have two fragments (one regular the other list), and when I run the setContentView on main_activity I notice that the onCreate of the regular fragment is being called, on the other hand the ListFragment onCreate is not being called.

Both of them are pretty much the same except that I didn't override onAttach + onDetach in the ListFragment (it was done for callbacks in the regular one).
What I did overwrote is: onCreate, onCreateView, onActivityCreated, onStart (to start an asynctask), onSaveInstanceState.

Can you tell me what the prblem is? since I get NullPointerEception in the fragmentManager for the ListFragment.

Somecode:

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mynews.mynews.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.mynews.mynews.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    <fragment android:id="@+id/rss_feed"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:name="com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews.NewsFeed"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_news_feed" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**On Activity:**

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                    getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
            mNewsFeed = (NewsFeed) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.rss_feed);
```

**On Fragment:**

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListAdapter adapter;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        adapter = new ListAdapter(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), generateData());

        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }
```

**On ListFragment:**

```
public class NewsFeed extends ListFragment
{
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    View feedView;
    ListAdapterFeed rssListAdapter;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;

    public NewsFeed() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```

**Adding the stacktrace:**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dxrz0925u3nfmgp/ddms7983186720865326533.trace

**LogCat:**

> 04-19 23:15:49.901  11473-11473/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews E/SELinux﹕
>   Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file
>   04-19 23:15:49.901  11473-11473/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews E/SELinux﹕
>   Function: selinux_android_load_priority [1], There is no sepolicy
>   version file 04-19 23:15:49.901  11473-11473/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews
>   E/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , loading version
>   is VE=SEPF_GT-N7100_4.3_0018 04-19 23:15:49.901 
>   11473-11473/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews E/SELinux﹕
>   selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded
>   from /seapp_contexts 04-19 23:15:49.906 
>   11473-11473/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling
>   CheckJNI 04-19 23:15:49.991  11473-11473/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews
>   I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk 04-19 23:15:49.991 
>   11473-11473/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews W/ActivityThread﹕ Application
>   com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
>   04-19 23:15:50.036  11473-11479/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews I/dalvikvm﹕
>   Debugger is active 04-19 23:15:50.191 
>   11473-11473/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews I/System.out﹕ Debugger has
>   connected 04-19 23:15:50.191  11473-11473/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews
>   I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle... 04-19 23:15:50.391 
>   11473-11473/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews I/System.out﹕ waiting for
>   debugger to settle... 04-19 23:15:50.591 
>   11473-11473/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews I/System.out﹕ waiting for
>   debugger to settle... 04-19 23:15:50.791 
>   11473-11473/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews I/System.out﹕ waiting for
>   debugger to settle... 04-19 23:15:50.996 
>   11473-11473/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews I/System.out﹕ waiting for
>   debugger to settle... 04-19 23:15:51.196 
>   11473-11473/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews I/System.out﹕ waiting for
>   debugger to settle... 04-19 23:15:51.396 
>   11473-11473/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews I/System.out﹕ waiting for
>   debugger to settle... 04-19 23:15:51.596 
>   11473-11473/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews I/System.out﹕ waiting for
>   debugger to settle... 04-19 23:15:51.796 
>   11473-11473/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews I/System.out﹕ waiting for
>   debugger to settle... 04-19 23:15:51.996 
>   11473-11473/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews I/System.out﹕ debugger has
>   settled (1310) 04-19 23:15:52.911 
>   11473-11473/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: still
>   suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1) 04-19 23:16:17.531 
>   11473-11479/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews I/dalvikvm﹕ TRACE STARTED:
>   '[DDMS]' 8192KB 04-19 23:16:17.546 
>   11473-11479/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews D/dalvikvm﹕ +++ active profiler
>   count now 1 04-19 23:16:24.391  11473-11473/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews
>   E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView 04-19
>   23:16:27.771  11473-12572/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews I/dalvikvm﹕
>   threadid=11: waiting for method trace to finish 04-19 23:16:48.961 
>   11473-11473/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews E/MyNews﹕
>   Exceptionjava.lang.NullPointerException 04-19 23:17:15.451 
>   11473-11479/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews D/dalvikvm﹕ +++ active profiler
>   count now 0 04-19 23:17:15.711  11473-11479/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews
>   I/dalvikvm﹕ TRACE STOPPED: writing 44458 records 04-19 23:17:15.711 
>   11473-11479/com.kfir.bs.mynews.mynews W/dalvikvm﹕ WARNING: a debugger
>   is active; method-tracing results will be skewed

Thanks in advance,
K

Comment: Just missing the logcat.

Comment: I can't seem to get logcat in Android Studio when catching exceptions...

Comment: *"I get NullPointerEception in the fragmentManager for the ListFragment"* - how do you know that without logcat or stacktrace?

Comment: I use the debugger to check the flow, do you want a stack trace?

Comment: Yes, sorry to use logcat name..

Comment: Added  trace and logcat

Comment: It will be better to provide your stacktrace here in code format (because I can't open it from my machine, sorry). However, put here the revelant part for your issue. Also, I might help someone to find the issue faster. Thank you.

Comment: Openning a trace file is pretty much straghit forward you need the DDMS from the sdk, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677144/how-can-i-open-trace-file-formattraceview-without-ddms

Comment: Any ideas? It seems weird, it struck me that maybe it's because of the drawer layout in activity_main?